# How to change URL parameter on page load using PHP?

Tags: php

When accessing `https://website.com/especific-page/` – I need a random ref number as parameter, for example, `https://website.com/especific-page/?ref=3398`.

But when I use `header("Location: ?ref=" . random_int(100, 9999) );` it results in an error:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly. An error occurred during a connection to website.com.

I need a server-side PHP solution. I'm using AMP, so there are limitations in using JavaScript.

Comment: What is de error

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Vaguely telling us “it results in an error”, without any specifics, is not a helpful problem description. (And if that error should be anything with “cannot add headers, headers already sent” - then please go research it, this has been asked about more times already than you’ll find grains of sand on a beach.)

Comment: Or maybe the error is that there was too many redirects? Well then you need to implement a check for whether such a parameter was already set in the currently requested URL, before you redirect again … and again … and again.

Comment: @CBroe Are you going for the Clairvoyant of the week award :) :)

Comment: And you should maybe also explain what the actual _purpose_ is here - so that we can determine, whether this needs to happen server-side and thereby with an additional request in the first place - or if maybe client-side URL manipulation via the History API could be sufficient already.

Comment: I've updated it with the error message and improved the context of the problem

Comment: header("Location: ./?ref=" . random_int(100, 9999) );

Comment: @LianSheng unfortunately no, the same error occurs. I think it's redirecting itself in a loop and that's causing this issue…

Answer (score 0):

You can change the approach to achieve that

```
<li onclick="redirectURL(parameter)">redirect to new URL</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectURL(parameter){
window.location.href = 'https://website.com/especific-page/'+parameter;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a server-side PHP solution. I'm using AMP, so there are limitation in using JavaScript